# Python 2.7 Bubble Sort

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, csv

I am trying to make my program sort the recorded scores that are in a csv file, my process of doing this is going to be reading the csv file into a list, bubblesort the list, then overwrite the csv file with the new list. I have encountered a logic error in my code however. When I sort the list the result is `[[], ['190'], ['200'], ['250'], ['350'], ['90']]`.

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated. Here is my code for my read and my bubble sort.

```
import csv

def bubbleSort(scores):
    for length in range(len(scores)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(length):
            if scores[i]>scores[i+1]:
                temp = scores[i]
                scores[i] = scores[i+1]
                scores[i+1] = temp


with open ("rec_Scores.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile)
    scores = list(r)

bubbleSort(scores)
print(scores)
```

This is my first time implementing a sort in python so any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: You need to convert your values from strings to integers. When you compare strings, you are comparing them lexicographically (i.e. in alphabetic order), not numerically.  So `100` comes before `9` because `9` is "bigger" than `1`

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that? I am still very new with Python, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings instead of integers. Use `int(scores[i])` to convert the string to an integer.

Upon further inspection looks like you are storing your numbers in a list of lists. In that case, to access the first number we must do `scores[0][0]` the second number would be `scores[1][0]` and so on... the first index is increasing by increments of one so we can use `int(scores[i][0]`.

The second numbers stays at 0 because it looks like you are only storing a single int in your inner list.

Comment: Could you tell me where to implement that please? The debug says that "int() argument must be with a string or a number, not 'list'"

Comment: @HarryBeggs Alright seems you are storing your numbers in a list of lists int that case to access the first element do int(scores[0][0])

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using strings in your scores list. If you want this sort to work correctly you need to convert your values to integers:

```
 int(str_num)
```

Where `str_num` is your string value.

This sort should work just fine after you do this conversion.
Also, you can use the built-in timsort to sort your numbers by calling

```
scores.sort()
```

Then you don't have to worry about implementing your own algorithm.

Comment: Where would I implement that line of code? Would it be after the "scores = list(r)" line?

Comment: You have to access each element of your string list and convert them individually to int and store in new list. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
import csv
with open ("rec_Scores.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile)
    scores = [int(item) for item in list(r)]
print(sorted(scores))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scores= list(r);
intscores = [0]*scores.len()
for str in scores:
    intscores.append(int(str))

intscores.sort()
```

This should do it.